# Calling web services dynamically from a console application

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio-2010, reflection

I am using this example from microsoft to call web services dynamically using reflection:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2006/04/27/dynamically-invoking-a-web-service.aspx

Which works fine in a web page project, however in a console application the class

```
ServiceDescriptionImporter
```

Is unavailable (doesnt come up in intellisense and isnt recognized as part of the assembly it belongs to -- System.Web.Services.Description). Which is wierd b/c it DOES come up in web projects.

Anyone know why this is? I cannot get the console app to work. This is a VS 2010 project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`ServiceDescriptionImporter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.description.servicedescriptionimporter.aspx) is in the System.Web.Services assembly. Add a reference to that, and import the namespace with a `using System.Web.Services.Description;` statement, and it will work.

Comment: The assembly is imported. For instance ServiceDescription works fine, but ServiceDescriptionImporter does not.

Comment: ServiceDescription is in another assembly than ServiceDescriptionImporter. The first is in `System.ServiceModel`, the second is in `System.Web.Services`. Do you have both assemblies referenced ?

Comment: Are you sure? Im using .NET 4, and according to MSDN :http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.description.servicedescriptionimporter.aspx They are both in System.Web.Services.Description. Assembly System.Web.Services.dll.

Comment: Tried referencing both assemblies, same problem.

Comment: There are TWO ServiceDescription classes. One is in the System.ServiceModel.Description namespace and the other is in the System.Web.Services.Description namespace. Really silly, I know... Make sure you've got the right using statement at the top of your file.

Comment: ServiceDescriptionImporter is supposed to be in System.Web.Services.Description, right? I have both the assembly added (system.web.services.dll) and the using statement at the top. Still doesnt show up. Keep in mind that this works fine in a web app project.

Comment: For anyone who may run into the same problem, I fixed this by downgrading to .NET 3.5. It must be a bug?

Answer (score 2):

I also met this problem.
when I went to change the target framework, I found the default target is **.Net Framework 4 client profile**, also there has a .Net Framework 4 exist. 
I changed the target from .Net Framework 4 client profile to .Net Framework 4, and then it's working, the ServiceDescriptionImporter appeared. 
hope this helps for others.