# How can I query a database on a second thread while my web application continues running?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, web-services

I want to start a new thread to query a database while my web application continues running. I was under the impression that by using threads I can run the querying process independently while the normal web application page cycle carries on, but I could be wrong.

```
public class DbAsyncQuery
{
    Dictionary<string, object> serviceResults = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    public void UpdateBillingDB()
    {
        QueryAllServices();

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> p in serviceResults)
        {
            IEnumerable results = (IEnumerable)p.Value;
            IEnumerable<object> sessions = results.Cast<object>();

            DbUtil.MakeBillingDBEntry(sessions, p.Key);
        }
    }

    public static string[] servicesToQuery = new string[]    // Must go in config file ultimately 
    {
        "xxx.x.xxx.xx"

    };

    public delegate void Worker(); 

    private Thread worker;

    public void InitializeThread(Worker wrk)
    {
        worker = new Thread(new ThreadStart(wrk));
        worker.Start();
    }

    public void InitializeQuery()
    {
        Worker worker = QueryAllServices;
        InitializeThread(worker);
    }

    private void QueryAllServices()
    {
        Dictionary<string, DateTime> lastEntries = DbUtil.GetLastEntries();

        foreach (string ip in servicesToQuery)
        {
            string fullServicePath =
                "http://" + ip + ":800/MyWebService.asmx";

            //object[] lastEntry = new object[] { lastEntries[ip] };
            object[] lastEntry = new object[] { new DateTime(2011, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0) }; 

            object obj = WebServiceHandler.CallWebService
                (fullServicePath, "MyWebService", "GetBillingDBEntries", lastEntry);

            serviceResults.Add(ip, obj);
        }
    }
}
```

It seems to basically stall and wait to finish the query before loading the page (which can be thousands of rows, so it takes awhile). I put this in the following section of `Global.asax`:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DbAsyncQuery query = new DbAsyncQuery();
    query.UpdateBillingDB(); 
}
```

This is one of my first web pages, and I'm new to threading. I understand there is a difference between creating your own thread and using the ThreadPool. In this method, I am using my own thread, I think. Not sure if that's the best way.

Any ideas? The querying process can be completely independent, and its only going to occur on scheduled intervals (every 8 hours or so). The user doesn't need to have up to the minute data, so it can take awhile. I just don't want the site to wait for it to finish, if that's possible.

Comment: Don't worry about thread pools. Doesn't matter yet. You need to get the basic setup working. What starts the DB update process? Basically, you need to create a thread, give it enough information so that it can do it's work and method to call you back when it's done, and then start the thread. Try getting that running in a app all by itself for starters. You have some of the basics there in your code above, but there's also a bunch of code missing.

Comment: Actually theres two parts to this. The query and then writing to another database.

The method call DbUtil.MakeBillingDBMethod writes to the new database with a loop that runs a stored procedure. 

The WebServiceHandler.CallWebService() method is what does the query, which obviously is coming from a web service.

Answer (score 1):

Since your database process runs on a schedule, then keep it out of the web application.  Create a console application that does this process and use Windows's Scheduled Tasks to schedule it to run every 8 hours.

Put code that is common to the database procedure and web site in a shared dll.

The reason you want to separate this is:

1. Web app won't run if there are no clients.  If you want this to run on a schedule, take control of the schedule, don't leave it up to clients hitting the website to trigger.
2. Separate resources.  Since this routine is long running keep the resources it uses separate from the web site.  Using a console app also 100% cleans up any resources it uses automatically when it closes.
3. Simpler to program.  While it may sound more complicated at first to manage separate products, separating them and concentrating on things one at a time will actually simplify development.
4. Run to completion.  The ASP.NET worker process recycles based on many conditions, including a set schedule, and a long-running process won't keep it from recycling.  If it recycles while your process is running, your process won't complete.  Separating it to a scheduled task will ensure it's allowed to run to completion regardless of ASP.NET worker process state or recycles.

Comment: That was actually my initial plan. However I couldn't get my console app to work. See this topic for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961845/calling-web-services-dynamically-from-a-console-application/4961883#4961883
What I would have it do in this case is anytime someone logs in check the logs to see when the last update was, if its over 8 hours ago then query on this new thread. If I can get the console app to work thatd be great too, though.

Comment: I agree with Samuel. This kind of thing should be done outside of your web application and set on a schedule and/or can be triggered by the web application if need be as well.

Comment: @Sean, why do you need a WebService/WCF to do this? Either ways, I'd stick with that solution rather than use the Web application. I also suggest provide a simple example of what doesn't work (for the other question) so people can provide the solution.

Comment: I posted a link, its a pretty short post explaining the problem when I tried this in console app. My web service exposes business objects that are mapped on top of relational data (Entity Framework ORM). Its not absolutely necessary, the alternative is SSIS for sql data consolidation I think, but I dont know much about that. I have a single client right now that needs to consolidate data from many servers (each exposing the service). I query them dynamically so that I can add new web references on the fly as we add more and more servers.

Comment: Fixed the console app, will go with that approach.